# SQL row values to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need help with something similar to PIVOT, but it isn't that easy.

I have table with this structure, and i need to get structure something like in the bottom of the picture:

[image: PICTURE with exampe]

Can anyone help me?
Thank you guys!

Comment: i reckon just to do it manually.. like a `case statement` for each column

Comment: What is the connection between CUSTOM_FIELD_ID and which CF column the value gets put in in the output? Also, is 2:value3 a typo? (Why 2 and not 3?)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - before you can say that, you must understand the question. I don't. Do you? If you do, can you edit the post to clarify the question? If not, let's wait for clarification first.

Comment: @mathguy: it is a "standard" pivot question. The only "difference" is that the concatenated value of two columns is "pivoted"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - What makes 6: ... go to the first column and 9: ... go to the second, in the second row? Is it just because 6 < 9? In any case, it is NOT a standard pivot question, since the column on which to pivot is not present in the table; it will likely have to be created with ROW_NUMBER or such, but I still don't know what goes in each CF column. I can guess, like you did, but sometimes our guesses aren't right; best for the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using a pivot:

```
with testdata as
(select 'first' casekey, 1 custom_field_id, 'value1' custom_field_value from dual union all
 select 'first' casekey, 2 custom_field_id, 'value2' custom_field_value from dual union all
 select 'first' casekey, 3 custom_field_id, 'value3' custom_field_value from dual union all
 select 'second' casekey, 6 custom_field_id, 'value1' custom_field_value from dual union all
 select 'second' casekey, 9 custom_field_id, 'value1' custom_field_value from dual)

select *
from(
select casekey, custom_field_id, custom_field_value,
       rank() over(partition by casekey order by custom_field_id) pivotRank
from testdata)
pivot(
    max(custom_field_id || ':' || custom_field_value)
    for pivotRank in (1 as CF1, 2 as CF2, 3 as CF3, 4 as CF4, 5 as CF5)
)
```

First I use a windowing function to rank the custom_field_id column partitioned by casekey. Then all you have to do is take the max of the concatenated fields you wanted and pivot 1 through 5 on the pivotRank.

My output for the above query looks like this:

```
casekey     CF1         CF2         CF3         CF4         CF5
first       1:value1    2:value2    3:value3    (null)      (null)
second      6:value1    9:value1    (null)      (null)      (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with y as (
    select cas, cfi || ':' || cfv cf, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cas order by cfi) n
    from x)
  , z AS (
    select DISTINCT cas
    FROM x 
  )
select z.cas, cf1.cf, cf2.cf, cf3.cf, cf4.cf, cf5.cf
from z
left join y as cf1 on z.cas = cf1.cas and cf1.n = 1
left join y as cf2 on z.cas = cf2.cas and cf1.n = 2
left join y as cf3 on z.cas = cf3.cas and cf1.n = 3
left join y as cf4 on z.cas = cf4.cas and cf1.n = 4
left join y as cf5 on z.cas = cf5.cas and cf1.n = 5
```